# Does require('./bar') try to load a file named 'bar' first or 'bar.js' first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Quoting from the article at https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8 below:

> We can natively require JSON files and C++ addon files with the require function. You don’t even need to specify a file extension to do so.
>
> If a file extension was not specified, the first thing Node will try to resolve is a `.js` file. If it can’t find a `.js` file, it will try a `.json` file and it will parse the `.json` file if found as a JSON text file. After that, it will try to find a binary `.node` file. However, to remove ambiguity, you should probably specify a file extension when requiring anything other than `.js` files.

Here is my little experiment that seems to contradict what is written above.

```
$ cat foo.js
console.log('I am foo.js!')
require('./bar')
$ cat bar.js
console.log('I am bar.js!')
$ cat bar
console.log('I am bar!')
$ node foo.js
I am foo.js!
I am bar!
$ node bar
I am bar!
```

The experiment shows that if I do not specify the `.js` extension name, i.e. I import only `bar` or try to run only `bar`, then the first thing Node tries to do is to find a file named exactly as `bar`. Therefore, it contradicts the following statement from the quoted article.

> If a file extension was not specified, the first thing Node will try to resolve is a `.js` file.

Is the quoted article incorrect or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article is incorrect. From [the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together):

> LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
>
> 1. **If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP**
> 2. **If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP**
> 3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP
> 4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP